# Silverstripe Gridfield filters not working

Tags: silverstripe

I have a site which I've just updated from 2.4 -> 3.1.

On my local environment everything works fine, but once uploaded to production the search filters on GridFields do not work. No errors that I can see, they just don't filter anything.

Has anyone come across this?

```php
class Product extends DataObject {

    static $db = array (
        'URLSegment'=>'Varchar(255)',
        'Name' => 'Text',
        'ProductCode' => 'Text',
        'Description' => 'Text'
    );

    static $has_one = array (
        'ProductPage' => 'ProductPage',
        'OverrideProductImage' => 'Image'
    );

    static $searchable_fields = array( 
        'Name',
        'Description', 
        'ProductCode' 
    );

    static $create_table_options = array(
        'MySQLDatabase' => 'ENGINE=MyISAM'
    );


    public function getCMSFields() {
        return new FieldList(
            new TextField('Name'),
            new TextField('ProductCode'),
            new TextareaField("Description","Description"),
            new Uploadfield("OverrideProductImage", "Product Image")

        );
    }
}
```

and

```php
class ProductPage extends Page {

    public static $db = array(
        'ShowOnHome' => 'Boolean'
    );

    static $has_many = array (
        'Products' => 'Product'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $f = parent::getCMSFields();

        $config = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();
        $config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(
            'Thumbnail' => 'Product Image',
            'Name' => 'Name',
            'ProductCode' => 'ProductCode', 
            'Description' => 'Description'
        ));

        $config->addComponent(new GridFieldOrderableRows());

        $productsField = new GridField(
            'Products', // Field name
            'Product', // Field title
            $this->Products(), 
            $config
        );

        $f->addFieldToTab('Root.Products', $productsField);

        return $f;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to tell which version of the framework you are using. Is it 3.1.10?

Comment: Version - Framework: 3.1.10, CMS: 3.1.10

Comment: Issue is quite likely related to suhosin limiting the length of the request( hence my question), as wmk mentioned. Fixed with https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/commit/a59e102c615aa15400d76415edf1abf965cc6ea0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have suhosin enabled on your live server? I stumbled over this problem last week, it will be fixed in 3.1.11 which is just around the corner. Maybe checkout the pre release you can download [here](http://www.silverstripe.org/software/download/#download-releases) (including composer command)

Suhosin unfortunately logs to syslog on my debian box, so I didn't find any errors first.

Had to update `suhosin.get.max_name_length` to get excel export working and `suhosin.post.max_name_length` to get pagination and column sorting / filtering working.

See [Github issue](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/3855)

Comment: Updated cms/framework with 3.1.11-rc1 and this has fixed the issue, thanks!